# Understanding the usecase of multiple recursive calls

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic-programming

I was trying to solve a problem to get all the possible valid combinations of parenthesis given an integer.  Eg. `input: n = 2, output: (()), ()()`

Clearly as `n` increases, the current output builds on the output of the previous n. So it was easy to come up with a recursive by taking the previous result and adding to it to get the current result:

```
HashSet<String> getCombinations(int n)
{
    HashSet<String> result = new HashSet<String>();
    if (n <= 0) return null;
    if (n == 1)
    {
        result.add("()");
        return result;
    }
    for (String str: getCombinations(n - 1))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            result.add(new StringBuffer(str).insert(i, "()").toString());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Though obviously the downside of the above code is the repetition of the same result values which are produced but not stored. So I looked online for a better solution (as I could not think of it), and found this:

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
void getCombinations(int index, int nLeft, int nRight, String str)
{
    if (nLeft < 0 || nRight < 0 || nLeft > nRight) return;
    if (nLeft == 0 && nRight == 0)
    {
        result.add(str);
        return;
    }
    getCombinations(index + 1, nLeft - 1, nRight, new StringBuffer(str).insert(index, "(").toString());
    getCombinations(index + 1, nLeft, nRight - 1, new StringBuffer(str).insert(index, ")").toString());
}
```

I understand how this solution works and why its better than the first. But even now I cannot imagine looking at the first solution and then coming up with second solution. How can I **intuitively** understand so as to when to use multiple recursive calls? In other words, after achieving solution 1, how can I come to think that I would probably be better off with multiple recursive calls?

My question is not specific to the above problem, but the type of problems in general.

Comment: I think the key hint is "divide and conquer". (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm ) It often implies multiple recursion calls.

Comment: Not sure I agree. I think this falls more in the realm of dynamic programming than divide and conquer, though I may be wrong. Like merge sort is divide and conquer - I can divide the problem clearly into 2 sub problems and finally combine the result. That doesn’t seem to be the case here. I am not diving the input into 2 as such.

Comment: Are you sure? It looks to me you divide your problem into two problems: the problem with the left hand side and the problem with the right hand side.

Comment: No, I’m not entirely sure. That’s why I posted here. Though I don’t feel it is. When I think about merge sort or matrix multiplication I clearly divide the input problem into 2, solve and combine. Though here that doesn’t seem to be the case, or at the least it’s not obvious (to me)!

Answer (score 0):

You could look at this problem as permutations of 1 and -1, which while being summed together, the running sum (temp value while adding up numbers left-to-right) must not become less than 0, or in case of parenthesis, must not use more right-parenthesis than left ones.
So:

If `n=1`, then you can only do `1+(-1)`.
If `n=2`, then can do `1+(-1)+1+(-1)` or `1+1+(-1)+(-1)`.

So, as you create these permutations, you see you can only use only one of the two options - either `1` or `-1` - in every recursive call, and by keeping track of what has been used with `nLeft` and `nRight` you can have program know when to stop.

Comment: I think you are trying to explain how the above solution works. Thats not what I was asking. I understand the logic and stop conditions etc. What I don't understand is how can I intuitively make the jump from solution1 to solution2. How can I think "hmm, in this case probably I would be better off with multiple recursive calls". Its not an easy question to ask :)

Comment: Well, once you understand that you can only append one of two - either `(` or `)`, you see it's a binary tree and you need multiple recursive calls to explore all leaves. How to jump from solution 1 to 2 is just picking different approach.

Comment: I'm not able to imagine this problem as a Binary Tree. Can you elaborate?